# How to improve the speed of list comprehension on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a faster way to filter items from a set other than list comprehension, the list comprehension run time is a bit slow for large dataset.

I have already converted the `list_stopwords` to a set, which takes less time compared to a list.

```
             date      description
0        2018-07-18    payment receipt
1        2018-07-18    ogsg s.u.b.e.b june 2018 salar
2        2018-07-18    sal admin charge
3        2018-07-19    sms alert charge outstanding
4        2018-07-19    vat onverve*issuance 


list_stopwords = set(stop_words.get_stop_words('en'))

data['description'] =  data['description'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (list_stopwords)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with regex works faster:

Fist create your match case regex:

```py
list_stopwords = set(stop_words.get_stop_words('en'))
re_stopwords= r"\b["
for word in list_stopwords: 
    re_stopwords+= "("+word+")"
re_stopwords+=r"]\b"
```

Now, apply on column:

```py
data['description'] =  data['description'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(re_stopwords,'',x))
```

This gona replace all stopwords with `''`(empty string).

I believe its faster becouse regex operate direct on the string, instead your code get a loop on a split.

- To understand more about regex lib: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).
- More about `\b` expression: [regular-expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#:%7E:text=The%20metacharacter%20%5Cb%20is%20an,called%20a%20%E2%80%9Cword%20boundary%E2%80%9D.&text=Before%20the%20first%20character%20in,character%20is%20a%20word%20character.).